# Как добавить status_code в django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Использую ModelViewSet. Как добавить вначале status_code?

Answer (score 1):

Импортируйте объект `status`, выберите нужный статус из методов объекта и добавьте его в `Response`
[Пример описан в документации](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#Marking)